# Is there any reason the Well-Known OpenID discovery endpoint is not signed?

Tags: openid, openid-connect

Unlike WS-Federation/WS-Trust metadata, the OpenID discovery endpoint is not signed. This results in a [number of threats](https://leastprivilege.com/2017/01/06/bootstrapping-openid-connect-discovery/) that are possible on this endpoint.

Is there any justification in not signing this endpoint? Is there limited effectiveness in doing so?